# join command in a loop

Tags: linux, join

I used join command to merge multiple files in my script.

```
while read line; do  
    join file1 "$line" > output  
    cat output > file1  
done < list
```

The thing is, as the loop progresses, more and more data are removed from the output file since not all entries matched across all data files. how can I preserve the unmatched data and be included in the output file?

Answer (score 0):

`man join` is your friend! Mine proposes option `-a`:

> ```
> -a file_number
>          In addition to the default output, produce a line for each
>          unpairable line in file file_number.
> ```

So you should use:

```
while read line; do
    join -a 1 file1 "$line" > output
    cat output > file1
    done < list
```

Comment: Thank you. I would like to ask follow-up question. some of the columns do not have any data. I have tried using -e 0 to fill them up, but somehow it does not work. What seems to be the problem with this?

Comment: @DalePin: You should ask a new question for that, showing an example of input that demonstrates the problem. It's too different to be a simple edit to this question, and without example data I cannot guess what can happen